# How do I find alternative methods in tensorflow latest release to deprecated one like tf.image_summary used in some tensorflow official tutorials?

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow. While I was reading the [CNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/deep_cnn/), I found a broken link to a deprecated method [image_summary](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train#image_summary).

- What is the best practice to follow in such situation?
- Shall I try to inform the tensorflow team about the broken links in their tutorials?

  - if so, what is the best channel to do so?
- How shall I find the best alternative to the deprecated method in their latest release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way might be a quick search into the Tensorflow Github repo. E.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=image+summary, where you'll see it's been renamed to tf.summary.image.

Surely it'll be much appreciated if you let the team know. I think the best way is to raise an issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues